# Display tooltips on controls on a PropertyPage. Crashes when returning TRUE to ON_NOTIFY_EX( TTN_NEEDTEXT...)

Tags: c++, mfc, tooltip

I have a class

> class CCfgUserPage : public CPropertyPage

Which also owns various controls, from check boxes to text areas. I would like to add tooltips to each control, and seem to be having issues.

In CCfgUserPage I added this to the message map

> ON_NOTIFY_EX(TTN_NEEDTEXT, 0, OnToolTipText )

Which when this object catches that message it calls the function OnToolTipText which looks like this

```
BOOL CCfgUserPage::OnToolTipText( UINT id, NMHDR * pNMHDR, LRESULT * pResult )
{
    TOOLTIPTEXT *pTTT = (TOOLTIPTEXT *)pNMHDR;
    UINT nID = pNMHDR->idFrom;
    CString ttStr;

    int partOrient = GetDlgItem(IDC_PARTORIENT_CHECK)->GetDlgCtrlID();

    if (pTTT->uFlags & TTF_IDISHWND)
    {
        // idFrom is actually the HWND of the tool
        nID = ::GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)nID);
        if( nID == partOrient ) // Only Display TT for The buttons with these ID's
        {
            if( nID == partOrient )
                ttStr = "Part Orient";
            pTTT->lpszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)ttStr;
            pTTT->hinst = AfxGetResourceHandle();
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I also enabled tool tips in

> CCfgUserPage::OnInitDialog

Whenever OnToolTipText returns TRUE the application crashes and informs me of

> Access violation reading location

I am trying to go through the stack frame but it is to far into MFC for me to understand what is going wrong. What might I be missing that would cause this to happen?

Comment: I don't really see a question in here. Or good explaination. There's too much missing here or I don't understand something. Also if it's MFC some extra tags could help?

Comment: `1` Don't cast your CHAR constrant to TCHAR* pointer `2` you don't need to initialize `hinst` (see MSDN why) `3` you can copy up to 80 characters into notification supplied buffer instead of returning your own pointer (this makes sure no memory issues involved afterwards).

Comment: Since you're using a `char` string instead of a `wchar_t` string, your string is likely not terminated with a 16-bit zero value; this will cause Windows to read well past the end of the string.

Comment: (@)Gam: I mean the problem is I cannot get tool tips to show up, whenever I move over a control that has a potential to show a tool tip the application crashes. If I were to say that in the question I would get down voted to oblivion. (@)Roman What do you mean by number 1 and 3. #1 I don't see Char or TChar in my code? Do you mean LPCTSTR? #3 I do not return a pointer.... (those are both way off I am sure)...

Comment: `1` - your "..." constant is CHAR* and you unsafely cast it to TCHAR* which is presumably WCHAR*; `3` - you do return a pointer by initializing a field with your `ttStr`, instead you can `_tcsncpy_s` your value into pointer already provided by `lpszText`

Comment: Bear with me Roman, I, as this website frequently points out, am a terrible programmer. (1 - your "...") what does that mean. Your ellipsis constant is a char pointer? I still do not see a CHAR in there anywhere, do you mean the LPCTSTR casting? You think I should make all my tool tip strings and then get pointers to them, and tcsncpy them to the TOOLTIPTEXT structure instead of setting the TOOLTIPTEXT pointer with a equal sign?

Comment: A string literal defined as "Whatever" is a string of char. For it to be a string of wchar_t, you have to define it as L"Whatever". And to define it as TCHAR (the compiler decides whether it is char or wchar_t, depending on UNICODE being defined or not) you have to do _T("Whatever") or TEXT("Whatever"). When you cast to LPTSTR or LPCTSTR you are using TCHAR, so your literals should be _T("Whatever").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the hint you have on MSDN:

> When you handle the TTN_NEEDTEXT notification message, specify the
>   string to be displayed in one of the following ways:
>
> - Copy the text to the buffer specified by the szText member.
> - Copy the address of the buffer that contains the text to the lpszText member.
> - Copy the identifier of a string resource to the lpszText member, and copy the handle of the instance that contains the resource to the
>     hinst member.

So instead of doing:

```
        CString ttStr;
        // ...
        if( nID == partOrient )
            ttStr = "Part Orient";
        // Below is the unsafe part: you initialize lpszText with something
        //       expected to be valid after you return from the handler
        //       effectively, this is internal buffer of local ttStr valriable
        //       which is to be freed and lpszText would keep point to undefined
        //       memory
        pTTT->lpszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)ttStr;
        pTTT->hinst = AfxGetResourceHandle();
```

You would rather:

```
        if(nID == partOrient)
        {
            // NOTE: Here instead you don't create any dynamic instances (strings)
            //       and the value resides directly in the notification structure
            _tcsncpy_s(pTTT->szText, _T("Part Orient"), _TRUNCATE);
            pTTT->lpszText = pTTT->szText; // Just a safety, it's already pointing there
        }
```

Comment: So the issues was with what I was telling the TOOLTIPTEXT structure. I was telling it some bogus stuff about the string to display and it believed me? The thing that just gets me is the code I posted was stolen from another part of my code that has worked for over a year with no issue, it does the same thing but it is on a CDialog derived page. What is the difference there that it would work one way and not the other?

Comment: Oh wait, it was even different problem, please have a look at updated answer.

Comment: Ahh I think I just read about this. I initialized ttStr in the Frame Buffer and not in the Heap buffer? So it was destroyed as soon as I hit the return TRUE statement, it then went to show the tooltip but the pointer pointed to crap so it said aww crap and crashed.

Comment: Yes it's about lifetime of the string and a pointer to its internal buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that ttStr goes out of scope at the end of the function and you are returning a pointer to it.  The pointer is now invalid and the app crashes when trying to reference it.

Use the supplied buffer if the tooltip will always be small (less than 80 characters) or use a member variable to store the tooltip text.